# Eloquent - Call to undefined relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I have a **users** table and a **permissions** table. It's a many-to-many relationship so I also have a **users_permissions** table with a **user_id** & **module_permission_id** column.

The user model has the following relationship:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'users_permissions', 'user_id', 'module_permission_id');
}
```

When I run my query, the result contains an empty permissions array.

```
User::with('permissions');
```

If I echo the query in the with, I get the error: **Call to undefined relationship [] on model [App\Models\User]**

```
User::with(['permissions', function($q) {
            echo $q->toSql();  
            die();
        }]);
```

The rest of the query works, it's just trying to get permissions which is failing.

Comment: `User::with('permissions');` only returns the query builder. Try running `User::with('permissions')->get();` and see what it returns. You can also run `User::with('permissions')->toSql();` to check if correct query is being formed.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was a coding convention issue related to camelCase vs. snake_case:
In the Model there was

```
public function getPermissions()
```

and in the query there was

```
User::with(['get_permissions'])
```

When I changed this to

```
User::with(['getPermissions'])
```

it started to work, although I'd say the Laravel way would be to use snake_case instead.

This confused me for a couple of days since frameworks like Symfony and AngularJs has a mixed conventions that somewhere you need to write parameters in snake_case and somewhere else in camelCase. I didn't find any documentation on Laravel site how they handle this, so I tried it the Straight Way and it seemed to be the case here :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just forgot the ->get() after User::with('permissions')->get() ?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems to be working now but I'm not sure why. Must have been something else on my query that was breaking it since the code I posted hasn't changed...

Answer (score 1):

Slapping this here for anyone who may be trying to refactor from an eager load that selects columns to an eager load with a scoped query.

You HAVE to move the selecting of columns into the scoped query, trying to select columns with the usual colon notation will fail and throw the undefined relationship error.

For example going from this eager load that selects a pivot table column, and a column from the permissions table `User:with('permissions:permission_tag:tag_set_id,permission_name')` to a scoped query that selects the same columns but also orders the results looks like this

```
  User::with([
    'permissions' => function ($query) {
      $query->select('permission_tag:tag_set_id', 'permission_name');
      $query->orderBy('permission_name');
    },
  ]);
```

Notice I pulled out the `:` notation and it lives right in the scoped query.